# How to use wget to convert webpage to multipart/related for email

Tags: email

So the aim is to have an event trigger the retrieval of a webpage and then have that webpage (including additional content like images and css) be turned into an email which is then sent via email. I am familiar with all of the pieces so it should be mostly glue other than retrieving the correct links and converting the links to be cid: links. Now, it seems like wget has already done a lot of the heavy lifting here since it can retrieve page requisites (-p) and convert links (-k). It doesn't seem to go the next step though.

Has anyone found a good way to do this? I may end up modding wget to do this. I would have asked there directly but their development stuff is pretty opaque.

Answer (score 0):

Wget is not intended to send the web page as email. As you wrote, it has retrieved the files, which is the scope of wget.

Comment: It does other things outside of that scope also. Being able to store a webpage as a single file would have applications outside of just email. And to be clear, I would not be expecting wget to send the email.